# How to find the time it takes to load an application in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am downloading an application and installing it. After that I am opening the application in python. I want to know how much time it takes to load the GUI application. How can we do this in python.

If it is a webpage, we can use the time module to compute times before the webpage call and after it. But I don't think this method works for the GUI application. I want to compute the time from the moment I called the app to the point when the screen is displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give is more detail as the applicaton you are loading ?
More over is it one you code ? If so there are call back functions when screen is loaded as after() for Tkinter as example

Comment: No it is not the application I developed. It is any other application on the desktop. For example it could be a game installed on your system. You open it through subprocess() from python. Then I need to figure out the time when it is loaded.

Comment: Please clarify what's wrong with using the standard timing technique you referred to.